# Create your own mouse event in a class

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I haven't been learning C# for very long and was wondering if it is possible to create a mouse event from another class?

The intention is that when a mousedown happens, something is drawn on a panel. I would like to do all this from a different class is this possible?

This is what I've already tried:

```
class Circle: Form1
{
    Graphics g;
    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black);


    // Making a event ?
    public event EventHandler<MouseEventArgs> MouseDown;
    protected void OnClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<MouseEventArgs> handler = MouseDown;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    public Circle()
    {
        g = this.panel1.CreateGraphics();
    }
    public void Mouse_Down(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Draw something 
        g.DrawLine(pen, 0, 0, 50, 50);
    }
}
```

}

So instead of calling the panel1_MouseDown event in this class I want to call it from the circle class:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
 

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // So instead of calling the panel1_MouseDown event in this class I want to call it from the circle class 
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why do you think you have to *call events*? `Circle` is derived from `Form1`, so it's a Form. Is that intentional, i.e., is it what you actually want to do? -- Why did you subscribe to the MouseDown event in the base class? -- BTW, this is horribly wrong: `Graphics g; [...] g = this.panel1.CreateGraphics();`: you need to use the Paint event of your Panel to draw stuff on its surface. You should also avoid a Panel class to draw, use a PictureBox instead (double-buffered on its own, the Panel class isn't). Or a Custom Control derived from `Control` (less *overhead*) with double-buffering enabled

Comment: My intention is to open the event from the circle class, but I have no idea how to do this

Comment: Are you sure that a Circle IS a Form, and that a Circle HAS a Panel? Don't you want to design that your form has a panel on which a Circle is drawn?

Comment: If the circle is drawn on the panel, then **there are no reason** to put drawing code in the form. That will make code hard to reuse in another form as you would have to repeat code that draw in each form. In fact, the panel should be a **User Control** that you can drop elsewhere (from the tool window once the code is compiled). Learn about the **DRY** (don't repeat yourself) principle.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can *"do all this from a different class"*

 Referring to the the example below:

1. In Form1 constructor create initializes the instance of the `Circle` class and passes to its constructor an instance of Form1.
2. Make sure that the control you want to draw on is public (`panel1` in the example).
3. Add `MouseDown` and `Paint` events to `panel1`.
4. Always use the `Paint` event to draw graphics - it's the best practice.
   More info on Control.Paint Event please: [read here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.paint?view=net-5.0)

**Form1:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Circle circle;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Start the measuring time for reauthentication
        circle = new Circle(this);
    }
}
```

**Circle Class:**

```
class Circle
{
    private Form1 Instance;
    public Circle(Form1 instance)
    {
        this.Instance = instance;
        // Make sure the access modifier of panel1 is Public and add mousedown event
        Instance.panel1.MouseDown += panel1_MouseDown;
        // Add a paint event - this is the best practice to draw graphics
        Instance.panel1.Paint += panel1_Paint; 
    }


    private int X;
    private int Y;
    private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.X = e.X;
        this.Y = e.Y;    
        // Redraw the panel when mouse is down
        Instance.panel1.Refresh();
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.X > 0 && this.Y > 0)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red);
            g.DrawEllipse(p, X, Y, 50, 50);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: A better design would be that panel would declare events like `CircleMouseDown` and hook them so that events become available in the designer where the panel is put. Also, when you manually hook an event, you should unsually un-hook it afterward.

Comment: The question asked by o.p is: "is it possible to create a mouse event from another class?"